# Adding records via check boxes in a nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

My form is nested so that a Cart has Products, which can have Features.  I wish to be able to add features to products via checkboxes.

Upon submit, rails is creating the Cart record, but failing to use "accepts_nested_attributes_for" to complete the addition of nested records.

My form is very straight forward, and I'm not receiving any errors, it's just ignoring the fields.  My fields look like this (within the form helper)

```
= f.fields_for :feature_line_items do |builder|
  = builder.check_box :id
  = builder.label :id, "Feature Label"
```

Thanks in advance, I'm kind of doubting this is even possible, and probably need to rethink my data architecture.

Answer (score 2):

Try [this episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes-revised) in railscasts. Also I suggest using [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) gem, it makes forms programming very simple and straight forward.

I hope that helped.

Comment: That did, I actually looked at that exact screencast but it uses a many-to-many where my app is actually a 1-to-many parent-to-child type relationship.  I think I will need to use check_box_tag no matter what to craft my own "names" for passing through.  I was hoping rails would just be able to "handle" this via accepts_nested_attributes.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look :

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes

http://ramblings.gibberishcode.net/archives/rails-has-and-belongs-to-many-habtm-demystified/17